# jQuery Return Newly Created Element

Tags: jquery, reference, append

I am using jQuery to create a new element when a button is clicked, the function is as follows:

```
function insert_ordered_group() {

    var template = 
        '<div class="row recipient-group">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-12 group-name-row handle">' +
                '<div class="dropdown">' +
                    '<a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="group-name">Group One</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></a>' +
                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                        '<li class="rename-group-tool">Rename Group</li>' +
                        '<li class="add-group-recipient">Add Recipient</li>' +
                        '<li class="remove-group-tool">Delete Group</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    // Add HTML to recipient form
    $('#ordered_recipients_sortable').append(template);


    return true;
}
```

Instead of returning true, is it possible to return a reference to the newly created object so that I can further manipulate it in the DOM? Due to the dynamic nature of this function, I would prefer not to generate an ID for each element and later reference it.

I've tried:

```
var test = $('#ordered_recipients_sortable').append(template);
console.log(test);
```

However, that only returned #ordered_recipients_sortable instead of the new element.

Thanks!

Comment: `var test = $(template).appendTo('#ordered_recipients_sortable')`

Comment: @adeneo Well.. that was quick! Thank you. Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: The alternative would have been to do a query inside the parent object.  `$('#ordered_recipients_sortable').find(".row recipient-group")`.  But yes, `appendTo()` is the better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `appendTo` instead, it returns the appended elements instead of the element that was appended to

```
var test = $(template).appendTo('#ordered_recipients_sortable')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function insert_ordered_group() {

    var template = 
        '<div class="row recipient-group">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-12 group-name-row handle">' +
                '<div class="dropdown">' +
                    '<a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="group-name">Group One</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></a>' +
                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                        '<li class="rename-group-tool">Rename Group</li>' +
                        '<li class="add-group-recipient">Add Recipient</li>' +
                        '<li class="remove-group-tool">Delete Group</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    // Add HTML to recipient form
    var appendTo = $('#ordered_recipients_sortable');
    appendTo.append(template);
    return appendTo.find(".row.recipient-group:last-of-type")

}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zxv4xszb/2/

This will always get the last one added.

Answer (score 0):

The answer @adeneo provided is exactly what I was looking for and more preferable than the solution I found while looking, however, this does work as well:

```
var new_element = $("#ordered_recipients_sortable .recipient-group:last-child");
```